# result of call back function return to view from model asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have one call back function in my model. i.e void method.
how to pass that result to view.

my problem is while uploading file to amazon s3, it's returning progress value. i need to get that value in view.

my code as follows

```
public bool sendMyFileToS3(EmployeeModel e, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket)
        {
            IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
            TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

            if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
            {
                request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name  
            }
            else
            {   // subdirectory and bucket name  
                request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
            }
            try
            {
                request.Key = RandomString() + Path.GetExtension(e.File.FileName); //file name up in S3  
                request.InputStream = e.File.InputStream;
                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                request.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(UploadFile_ProgressBar); //call bcak function
                utility.Upload(request);
            }
            catch(AmazonS3Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
             //commensing the transfer  

            //Generate link with expiry date.
            Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest aa = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
            aa.BucketName = request.BucketName;
            aa.Key = request.Key;
            aa.Expires = new DateTime().AddDays(2);
            string url = client.GetPreSignedURL(aa);
            url = url.Remove(url.IndexOf('?'));
            return true;  
        }
        public void UploadFile_ProgressBar(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
        {
            int pctProgress = (int)(e.TransferredBytes * 100 / e.TotalBytes);
        }
```

every second "pctProgress" this parameter is replacing with new value. when ever replacing with new value it should pass to view.
how to do this. 
please any suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried? You might want to asynchronously update the UI via javascript.

Comment: no, it's MVC project. above code present in model.

Comment: output of this (UploadFile_ProgressBar) method i need to pass back to UI via controller